# Assembly divisions and floating points

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

```
  mov eax, 0x01
  mov ecx, 0x02
  div ecx                 ; Divide AX/CX, saves remainder in DX
  cmp dx, 0
  je OddNumber
  int 80h
```

When I try to divide 1/2, instead of going to label OddNumber, it returns "Floating point exception". I know 1/2 is a float, but how can I handle it? Thanks.

GDB says "Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception." by the way.

Comment: to check for zero [use `test` instead of `cmp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33724806/995714)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. You need to zero `edx` before calling `div ecx`. When using a 32-bit divisor (e.g, `ecx`), `div` divides the 64-bit value in `edx:eax` by its argument, so if there's junk in `edx`, it's being treated as part of the dividend.
2. After the `div`, you probably want to compare `edx`, not just `dx`.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer seems to be covered in this [floating point exception may mean division by 0](http://en.chys.info/2009/12/floating-point-exception/) post. Can you have a look at what is in edx before the div?