# Floating Point Exception - Division between integers

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

```
mov rax, 6
mov rbx, 2
div rbx       ; rax = 6/2 = 3 - FLOATING POINT EXCEPTION
```

Error: **Floating Point Exception**.

As I suppose, I think it's because instead of going to the **ALU** (Arithmetical Logical Unit) it goes to the **FPU** (Floating Point Unit) which means it returns a float instead of an integer. Am I right?

Which would mean, that the **FPU** wouldn't handle the two Integers I provided so it produces a **Floating Point Exception**.

But how do I divide two integers then? Or if my guess is wrong, what's my mistake?

Comment: The division takes the 128 value in rdx:rax and divides it by _rbx_ with when you do `div`. I suspect there is data in _RDX_ that is causing the division to overflow. For unsigned division you can simply set _RDX_ to 0. This question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416593/why-should-edx-be-0-before-using-the-div-instruction/38416896#38416896 . The overflow of the itneger division is being reported to you with a generic "Floating Point Exception". It should be interpreted as "Arithmetic Exception"

Comment: Use shifts to divide by powers of 2, [it's **much** faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354978/why-is-this-c-code-faster-than-my-hand-written-assembly-for-testing-the-collat), especially for 64-bit operand-size.

Comment: I'm well aware of that, although a very nice advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux maps the `#DE` (division by zero exception) generated by the CPU to the `SIGFPE` signal, which is then translated to the human-readable error message "Floating point exception"; unfortunately, it's quite misleading, as no floating point at all is involved into the process.

Now, given that `rbx` is `2`, of course you are not dividing by zero. Still, there's another case when x86 generates a `#DE` exception: if the result is too big to fit into the target register.

In your code you are using the 64 bit form of the instruction (you wrote `rbx` - a 64 bit register - as divisor) which means that you are asking to divide `rdx:rax` (i.e. the 128 bit value obtained by joining `rdx` and `rax`) by `rbx`, and to put the result into `rax` (quotient) and `rdx` (remainder).

Since you are not zeroing out `rdx`, most probably it contains some big garbage value (residual from some previous computation?), and the division by two results in a quotient too big for `rax`. Hence, the `#DE` exception.

Long story short: zero out `rdx` before the `div` and everything will work out smoothly.

Comment: Question: But doesn't `mov` set the whole register to a whole different value?
Reply: Tried your request via setting it to 0 first with `xor rbx, rbx` and `mov rbx, 0` but didn't work, still same exception

Comment: @ApostolisAnastasiou: `mov` does set the whole register, the problem is that a `div` with a 64-bit divisor operand operates on `rdx:rax` (a *pair* of registers) as a source, and you only assigned to `rax`. As for your reply, you have to zero out `rdx`, not `rbx`!

Comment: It's [this exact situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649180/assembly-divisions-and-floating-points), only with the 64-bit version of `div` (which works on the larger registers).

Comment: Oh! Now I see! I didn't even know that division op actually saved the remainder somewhere. So each division should be followed by a rdx=0?

Comment: Each division should be *preceded* by a `rdx=0` - it's not just division that clobbers `rdx`!